# D3 collapsible tree with React: not updating nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, treechart

I am using `d3` collapsible tree, the code for which I copied from:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I am trying to accomodate it for my `React` web app and change it, so that I could append nodes to any tree nodes myself. It is appending nodes, creating links correctly, except that text at the nodes positions are not changed and the nodes are not collapsing/expanding when clicking on them. So, these are two my main issues that I believe are very related to each other. Here is what I am doing:

Inside of `componentDidUpdate` I am calling the function that is creating and updating the tree chart:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   this.updateGeneTreeChart(this.getRoot());
}
```

Update happens when I am selecting (using basic html `select`) node value to append next node to, and entering in a text field the value and then hit a button. So, I set the node to append to and text of the new node.

`updateGeneTreeChart` is:

```
updateGeneTreeChart = (source) => {
const svg = d3.select(this.node);
//svg.selectAll("*").remove();
const margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120};
const width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
const height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
let i = 0;
const duration = 750;

let root = this.getRoot();

let tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

let diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

let nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);
console.log("root.children");
console.log(root);
console.log(root.children);
/*if (this.state.selectedGeneArr.length) {
  root.children.forEach(this.collapse, this);
}*/
// Normalize for fixed-depth.
nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

// Update the nodes…
let node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
let nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
    .on("click", this.clickNode);

node.attr("text", function(d) {
  return d.name;
});


nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

// Transition nodes to their new position.
let nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
let nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

// Update the links…
let link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
      return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    });

// Transition links to their new position.
link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
      return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .remove();

// Stash the old positions for transition.
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.y0 = d.y;
});
}
```

`getRoot()` function is just getting a deep copy of the updated object that I am using to build the tree:

```
getRoot = () => {
  const margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  let root = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.geneTreeJSON));
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;
  return root;
}
```

`geneTreeJSON` is the actual object that I am updating. I am sure that it is updated correctly, that its structure is right, that the `nodes` object in the `updateGeneTreeChart` is correct:

[image]

However, all the newly attached nodes either have no text or have the text of the root node (in this particular case - `Il4ra`).
If I delete everything inside of `svg` at the beginning of each update it actually draws the right text at the nodes. So, somehow the text is not updating. I tried to do the following:

```
node.attr("text", function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });
```

OR

```
nodeEnter.attr("text", function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });
```

Not working. I tried then to print out what is passed to the nodes:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d) {
      console.log("nodeEnter");
      console.log(d); 
      return d.name; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

And `d` is the root node, children are not printed out. So, I guess this is where the issue of text at least should be fixed but I do not know how. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which D3 version are you using?

Comment: Not working on the project anymore, but it should be some old version that was there at the end of `2017`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the text of the nodes by adding the code:

```
// Update the nodes…
let node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

---->    node.select("text")
           .data(nodes)
           .text(function(d) {
                return d.name; });
```